# Why does the page refresh when I click on a historical search for the first time?

Tags: javascript

New coder here,

I'm creating a weather dashboard that keeps a history of each city after you search it. I should be able to click on a city I have previously searched and have it "re-search" that city and give me the expected results. But for some reason when I click on a city I have previously searched, it reloads the page instead. However, cnce the page is reloaded the buttons to search a previous entry work as expected but I can't figure out how to just make the button work--rather than reload and THEN work. (I already tried using event.preventDefault())

Thanks for your help!

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Weather Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 w-100 text-center">Weather Dashboard</span>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 bg-light">
                <p class="search-header my-1">Search for a City</p>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <input id="city-input" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter city name" aria-label="Enter city name">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="search-button">
                            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary mb-3" type="button" id="clear-history">Clear history</button>
                
                <!-- Add Search History -->
                <form id="history"></form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="row mr-0">
                    <div class="col-12 border border-dark m-3 rounded">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <span id="city-name" class="city-name align-middle"></span>
                                <img id="weather-icon">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p id="temperature"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p id="humidity"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <p id="wind-speed"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12 d-flex">
                                <div id="UV-index"><span id="UV-val"></span></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h3>5-Day Forecast</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- This is where the 5 day forecast is appended -->
                <div id="add-forecast" class="row">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```javascript
$(document).ready(function(){

    var APIKey = API;
    var cityName;

    $("#search-button").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        cityName = $("#city-input").val();

        if (cityName !== "") {
        
            renderWeather();
            renderForecast();
            autoSaveHistory();    
        
        };
       
        });    
    
      function renderWeather() {

      var queryURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityName + "&appid=" + APIKey

      $.ajax({
          url : queryURL,
          method : "GET"
      }).then(function(response){
        //   console.log(queryURL);
        //   console.log(response);
          
          var cityName = response.name;

          var icon = response.weather[0].icon;
          var iconURL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + ".png"

          var temp = response.main.temp;
          var humidity = response.main.humidity;
          var windSpeed = response.wind.speed;
          var lat = response.coord.lat;
          var lon = response.coord.lon;

          var uvQuery = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/uvi?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=" + APIKey
              

              // UV Index API
              $.ajax({
                  url : uvQuery,
                  method : "GET"
              }).then(function(response){
                  var UV = response.value;
                  UV = Number(UV);

                  if (UV >= 8) {
                      $("#UV-val").addClass("danger-zone");
                  } else {
                      $("#UV-val").removeClass("danger-zone");
                      $("#UV-val").addClass("safe-zone");
                  };
                  
                  $("#UV-val").text("UV Index: " + UV);
              });

          temp = Number(temp)
          temp = (Math.round((temp - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32))

          $("#city-name").text(cityName + " " + (moment().format("(MM/DD/YY)")));
          $("#weather-icon").attr("src", iconURL);
          $("#temperature").text("Temperature: " + temp + " \u00B0F");
          $("#humidity").text("Humidity: " + humidity + "%");
          $("#wind-speed").text("Wind Speed: " + windSpeed + " MPH");
        });

    };

    function renderForecast() {

    var fiveDayQuery = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" + cityName + "&appid=" + APIKey
    
    $.ajax({
        url : fiveDayQuery,
        method : "GET"
    }).then(function(response){
        // console.log(response);
        
        $("#add-forecast").text("");
        var days = 0;

        for (var i = 4; i < 37; i+=8) {

            var forecast = $("<div>");
            forecast.addClass("col forecast bg-primary text-white ml-3 mb-3 rounded");

            var dateP = $("<p>");
            var iconP = $("<img>");
            var tempP = $("<p>");
            var humidityP = $("<p>");

            var forecastTemp = response.list[i].main.temp;
            forecastTemp = Number(forecastTemp)
            forecastTemp = (Math.round((forecastTemp - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32));

            var forecastHumidity = response.list[i].main.humidity;
            var forecastIcon = response.list[i].weather[0].icon;
            
            var forecastIconURL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + forecastIcon + ".png"

            days++;
            dateP.text(moment().add(days, 'days').format('MM/DD/YY'));
            dateP.css("font-size", "20px");
            forecast.append(dateP);

            iconP.attr("src", forecastIconURL);
            forecast.append(iconP);

            tempP.text("Temp: " + forecastTemp + " \u00B0F");
            forecast.append(tempP);

            humidityP.text("Humidity: " + forecastHumidity + "%");
            forecast.append(humidityP);

            $("#add-forecast").append(forecast);
        };

      });

    };


var searchHistory = {
        "cityName": []
    };

var pullHistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("search"));

if (localStorage.getItem("search") !== "undefined") {
setHistory();
}

    function setHistory() {
            
        for (var m = 0; m < pullHistory.cityName.length; m++){
            console.log("test", pullHistory.cityName[m]);

            searchHistory.cityName.push(pullHistory.cityName[m]);
            localStorage.setItem("search", JSON.stringify(searchHistory));    
        }
        
        addHistoryItems();
    };

    function addHistoryItems() {
        $("#history").text("");

        pullHistory = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("search"));

        for (var k = 0; k < pullHistory.cityName.length; k++) {
            
            var cityName = pullHistory.cityName[k];

            var searchItem = $("<div>");
            searchItem.addClass("row");

            var searchButton = $("<button>");
            searchButton.attr("index-name", cityName);
            searchButton.addClass("history-btn");
            searchButton.text(cityName);

            searchButton.addClass("btn btn-primary btn-lg");
            searchButton.css({"text-transform" : "capitalize" , "margin" : "5px"});
            searchItem.append(searchButton);

            $("#history").append(searchItem); 
        };
    };

    function autoSaveHistory() {        

        searchHistory.cityName.push(cityName);
        localStorage.setItem("search", JSON.stringify(searchHistory));

        addHistoryItems();
    }

    $(".history-btn").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log("checked")

        cityName = $(this).attr("index-name");
        
        renderWeather();
        renderForecast();

    });


    $("#clear-history").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        localStorage.clear();
        $("#history").text("");
        
        searchHistory = {
            "cityName": []
        };
        localStorage.setItem("search", JSON.stringify(searchHistory));

    });

});
```

Comment: check out your history-btn event functions one by one I guess problem is in renderWeather() function. first disable it and try one forecast if than disable forecast and check weather.

Answer (score 0):

because  when click  city item, it trigger `<form id="history"></form>` default behavior : form submit .

so, `event.preventDefault()` need in form summit handler , not button click handler  , like this:

```
$('form#history').submit((event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   // ....
})
```

BTW, for jquery,  return false has the same effect .

Comment: This results in me not being able to click the historical search buttons at all.